# Карманы в регулярных выражениях

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

В книге Д. Котерова есть глава "карманы регулярок", но слабо понимаю, что это. Может мини лекцию кто-то проведет или ссылки, или книги, где это описано.

Может это имеет другое название?

Comment: Свяжу с http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538170/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Вкратце:

```
preg_match('/([abc]+)([0-9]+)(?:[a-z0-9]+)/',,);
```

Почти все, что между // заключено в круглые скобки будет запомнено в специальных временных переменных. Странное название "карманы" слышу первый раз, но да ладно.
/..../ соответствует нулевому карману. То есть все, что совпало с полным выражением, попадет в переменную $0.
([abc]+) - это первый карман.
([0-9]+) - второй.
(?:[a-z0-9]+) - вообще никакой, так как слово ?: говорит о том, что данную группировку запоминать не надо.

Чтобы подробнее это понять, составьте сложную регулярку, сделайте `preg_match_all` по длинному тексту, а потом результат распечатайте с помощью `print_r`.

Comment: спасибо за ссылочку

Comment: Ссылка более не работает.

Comment: Убрал ссыль вообще. На вебархиве она еще валяется, но туда никто лазить не будет. Спасибо.