# Атомарная группировка, сверхжадный квантификатор

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

1. Расскажите как работает атомарная группировка и сверхжадный
   квантификатор
2. Объясните как работают данные регулярные выражения

   1. `(?>#.*#)`
   2. `(?:(?>#.*#)|(A))`

Comment: Опять вопрос с кучей подвопросов с непонятной сутью :)

Comment: @ReinRaus а что непонятно то? если бы где-то это четко объяснялось я бы и не спрашивал, хочу разобраться всего лишь то!

Comment: Группировка "без обратной связи" не вписывается в остальной список. Это просто группировка без сохранения результата в ней. То же самое, что и обычная группировка, но без сохранения. Вот атомарная группировка и сверхжадная квантификация - относятся к одной теоритической теме. Их можно объединить в один вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос сформулирован так, что он является набором непонятно чего. Ведь можно сформулировать очень просто "Что такое атомарная группировка и сверхжадная квантификация". "Что выведет онлайн парсер" - это к чему вообще? Вы хотите узнать что выведет парсер или что делают эти виды группировок ?

Comment: Мне интересно объяснение этих примеров, я вот допустим не понимаю почему так выбирает или не выбирает

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос проще, чтобы можно было не стыдясь на него потом закрывать схожие вопросы и я постараюсь дать максимально развернутый ответ, а в такой формулировке, даже овечать лень :)

Comment: @ReinRaus Надеюсь так нормально?^^^

Comment: Нормально. Только из пункта 2 вопроса я объяснил регулярное выражение 1. Регулярное выражение 2 - то же самое, только результат сохраняется в группу 1 (прочтите http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/122778/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85 ) регулярное выражение 3- то же самое, без сохранения в группу и еще добавляется альтернатива с сохранением в группу литерала `A`. Итог: пункт 2 в вопросе не нужен, так как относится к другим темам, гораздо более простым

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы понять, что такое атомарная группировка и сверхжадная кванификация- нужно хоть немного понять как устроен движок регулярных выражений внутри, а точнее, нужно иметь представление о точках возврата.
С этого и начнем.

---

## Точка возврата

Встретив квантификацию или альтернативу (я рассматриваю простые случаи, на самом деле точки возврата создаются и в других конструкциях регулярных выражений- везде, где может потребоваться вернуться назад) движок регулярных выражений (далее просто "движок") создает точку, куда ему следует вернуться, если выражение не совпадет с текстом. Тогда вернувшись в эту точку он попробует применить альтернативу или прекратить квантификацию.
Что это означает?
Посмотрим на простое регулярное выражение `.*x` примененное к тексту `text` (точки возврата буду обозначать символом `.` :

1. Движок начинает обрабатывать текст с самого начала и видит `.*`, так как данное выражение может совпать с "ничем", то создаем точку возврата сюда `.text`
2. Смотрим дальше - далее по тексту литерал `t`, захватываем его как часть `.*` и надо бы создать точку возврата снова в позиции 0, но это было сделано уже в пункте 1. `.text`
3. Далее по тексту литерал `e`, захватываем его как часть `.*` и создаем точку возврата перед ним `.t.ext`
4. Далее по тексту литерал `x`, захватываем его как часть `.*` и создаем точку возврата перед ним `.t.e.xt`
5. Далее по тексту литерал `t`, захватываем его как часть `.*` и создаем точку возврата перед ним `.t.e.x.t`
6. Литералы кончились, это конец строки, но выражение не совпало, потому что требуется обязательно литерал `x`
7. Возвращаемся в точку возврата перед литералом `t`, теперь у нас выражению `.*` соответствует текст `tex`, и пытаемся найти за ним литерал `x` - неудача, так как за ним литерал `t`
8. Снова пробуем вернуться назад. Для этого возвращаемся в точку возврата перед литералом `x`. Теперь выражению `.*` соответствует текст `te`, ищем за ним литерал `x` и успешно находим
9. Регулярное выражение закончилось, значит найдено совпадение.
10. Итак: Выражению `.*` соответствует текст `te`, выражению `x` соответствует текст `x`, значит полное совпадение будет с текстом `tex`

Если бы у нас кончились точки возврата, и совпадения так и не найдено- значит текст не соответствует регулярному выражению.
Важно проникнуться механикой создания точек возврата- с пониманием этого быстро придет понимание различных видов квантификаций и атомарной группировки.

---

## Атомарная группировка: теория

Это группировка ВНУТРИ которой нет точек возврата.
Это означает, что как только будет найдено совпадение для выражения внутри такой группировки - это совпадение будет считаться единственным и вернуться внутрь него будет нельзя, даже, если это помешает общему совпадению.
https://regex101.com/r/cH7rO2/1

Выражение `(?>#.*#)a` применено к тексту `aaa#aaaaaa#aaaaaaaa#a#` - нет совпадений, потому что `#.*#` захватит самое большое совпадение `#aaaaaa#aaaaaaaa#a#` и внутри этого текста нет точек возврата - вернуться некуда, поэтому невозможно будет захватить литерал `a`, который следует за `(?>#.*#)`

Рассмотрим пошагово на тексте покороче `b#c#a#`

1. По тексту литерал `b` - не совпадает с обязательным `#`, переходим к следующему литералу
2. По тексте литерал `#` - совпадает с обязательным литералом `#`, переходим к выражению `.*` и запоминаем, что мы находимся внутри атомарной группировки и как только найдем совпадение для нее, то удалим все точки возврата, которые были созданы внутри нее
3. Захватываем литерал `c`, так как он соответствует `.`, создаем точку возврата перед ним `b#.c#a#`
4. Захватываем литерал `#`, так как он соответствует `.`, создаем точку возврата перед ним `b#.c.#a#`
5. Захватываем литерал `a`, так как он соответствует `.`, создаем точку возврата перед ним `b#.c.#.a#`
6. Захватываем литерал `#`, так как он соответствует `.`, создаем точку возврата перед ним `b#.c.#.a.#`
7. Достигли конца текста, но не нашли совпадения для литерала `#`. Вернемся в точку возврата перед последней решеткой. Теперь выражению `.*` соответствует текст `c#a`, выражению `#` - текст `#`
8. Мы достигли конца атомарной группировки, значит можно удалить все точки возврата, которые были созданы внутри нее. В итоге не останется ни одной точки возврата.
9. Нет точек возврата, а нужно еще совпадение с выражением `a`, которого нет после текста `#c#a#`. Результат - нет совпадений.

Подведем итог: пока ищется совпадение с атомарной группировкой - могут быть созданы точки возврата, но как только совпадение найдено - все точки возврата внутри атомарной группировки будут удалены.

---

## Атомарная группировка: практика

На практике атомарная группировка означает очень простую вещь - текст, который захвачен этой группировкой будет рассматриваться далее как единое целое внутрь которого нельзя вернуться.
Если что-то совпало - значит оно и будет результатом для атомарной группировки, иначе никак. Поэтому она и называется **атом**арной, то есть неделимой на отдельные части.

На практике атомарная группировка служит обычно для оптимизации регулярных выражений, наиболее часто ее можно увидеть в рекурсивных регулярных выражениях.
Примеры оптимизаций приведу при рассказе о сверхжадной квантификации.

## Сверхжадная квантификация

Это частный случай атомарной группировки, когда атомарная группировка применена в пределах одного квантификатора.
Вот и все, что следует о ней сказать.
Выражение `a++` полностью равносильно выражению `(?>a+)`.

Например выражение `a++a` не даст совпадения на тексте `aaaa`, потому что `a++` захватит все литералы `a`, которые есть в тексте и не вернет ни одного из них, хоть это и помешает общему совпадению.

Сверхжадная квантификация может выглядеть в регулярных выражениях следующим образом:

```
*+
++
?+
{m,n}+
```

## Примеры применения

### Оптимизируем минимальную квантификацию `.*?`

Пусть есть выражение `a.*?bcd` и текст `a-----bcd----bcd`
https://regex101.com/r/cH7rO2/8
Совпадение найдено за 11 шагов.
Теперь изменим регулярное выражение на такое `a(?:[^b]++|b)*?bcd`
https://regex101.com/r/cH7rO2/9
Совпадение найдено за 9 шагов.

Даже на таком маленьком тексте мы получили прирост примерно 20%

Смысл оптимизации в том, что смотрим литерал, который следует за минимальной квантификацией - в данном случае это `b`, и разлагаем минимальную квантификацию на две альтернативы из `b++` и `b` к которым тоже применена минимальная квантификация. Такая конструкция создает меньше точек возврата, поэтому быстрее происходит нахождение совпадения.

### Оптимизируем рекурсивные регулярные выражения

Возьмем каноническую задачу по поиску сбалансированных скобок `<>`
Сначала напишем регулярное выражение:

```
<(?:[^<>]*|(?R))*>
```

https://regex101.com/r/cH7rO2/4

Оно даже работает и мы могли бы радоваться жизни, но попробуйте добавить в начало текста `<` и по одному символу `a` постепенно ;) Радость будет таять на глазах при виде цифры шагов - количество шагов удваивается с каждым введенным символом, а потом и вовсе видим `Catastrophic backtracking`
https://regex101.com/r/cH7rO2/5
А оптимизируется все очень просто - достаточно не возвращаться назад внутри выражения `[^<>]*` Таким способом:

```
<(?:[^<>]*+|(?R))*>
```

https://regex101.com/r/cH7rO2/6

Или таким:

```
<(?:(?>[^<>]*)|(?R))*>
```

https://regex101.com/r/cH7rO2/7

Comment: Если что не ясно - пишите в чате, попробую объяснить, заодно может ответ поправлю в сторону более лучшего изложения мысли.

Comment: 1. Ни разу не пользовался чатом и не знаю где он

2. `a(?:[^b]++|b)*?b` - почему именно так, а не так: `a(?:[^b]++)*?b`, зачем было ставить литерал альтернативы на символ b после сверхжадной квантификации?

Comment: Да, верное замечание для неочевидной вещи. Оптимизация идет по первому литералу, который следует за минимальной квантификацией. Литералов же может быть множество, но оптимизируем по первому.

Comment: Не хочу оффтопить, но я так и не понял момент где используется рекурсия

Comment: Рекурсивные шаблоны - отдельная тема, ее тоже можно долго раскрывать, в рамках данного вопроса я лишь показал как правильно составить рекурсию, чтобы не получить `Catastrophic backtracking` - ситуация, когда движок превышает ограничение на максимальное количество точек возврата.

Comment: Предложу такую регулярку вместо вашей последней `<(?>[^<>]+|(?R))*>` - гораздо быстрее находит (из-за групп, у вас их в избытке)

Comment: У меня ни одной группы нет :) `(?:...)` это группа без сохранения результата. Просто группировка выражений.

Comment: Как обычно, мегаответ.