# Что такое группа захвата в регулярных выражениях?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Что такое группа захвата в регулярных выражениях, зачем она нужна и как ее использовать?

Comment: обычно регулярка отвечает на вопрос - удовлетворяет ли переданная строка описанному выражению, то есть ответ: да/нет, группа позволяет получить конкретную часть строки, удовлетворяющую выражению

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Группа захвата — это часть шаблона регулярного выражения, заключённого в круглые скобки; при совпадении шаблона с сопоставляемой строкой та часть строки, которая соответствует шаблону в скобках, будет помещена в результирующий массив в качестве отдельного элемента.

---

**Пример 1**

```js
alert( 'Hello, World!'.match(/World!/) ); // World!
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6jypate5/

В примере выше выведется та часть строки, с которой совпал шаблон: `World!`.

---

**Пример 2**

```js
alert( 'Hello, World!'.match(/World(!)/) ); // World!,!
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pt7geaLx/

А в этом примере помимо части строки, с которой совпал шаблон: `World!`; выведется ещё и та часть строки, которая совпала с шаблоном в круглых скобках: `!`.

---

Группу захвата ещё называют подмаской или подшаблоном (subpattern)... Их предназначение не только в том, чтобы помещать совпавшую часть строки в результат, но и в том, что к ним можно обращаться из других мест шаблона ...

---

Литература:

- [Learn.JavaScript.Ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions-javascript);
- [Ru.WikiBooks.Org](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F);
- [CyberForum.Ru](http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-regex/thread631382.html);
- [PHP.Net](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.introduction.php).